# Swift seems to be slower as Objective-C in loops

Tags: swift

I'm trying to port some code from Objective-C to Swift, with which I parse HTML documents. I'm using basically the NSXMLDocument and created own classes for HTMLDocument and HTMLNode to bring some extra functionality like getElementByID and so on.

If I now compare the ported code, the parsing in Obj-C needs 0.098 seconds, the code in Swift needs 0.49 seconds! I partly commented out the code and I could see, that it correlates with some loops, in which I "translate" the NSXML part to my own class. For example:

```
func getElementsByTagName(tagName: String) -> HTMLNode[] {
    let xPath = ".//\(tagName)"
    let xmlNodes = xmlElement.nodesForXPath(xPath, error: nil)
    var htmlNodes = HTMLNode[]()
    if xmlNodes.count > 0 {
        for element in xmlNodes as NSXMLNode[] {
            var node = HTMLNode(xmlElement: element as NSXMLElement)
            htmlNodes.append(node)
        }
    }
    return htmlNodes
}
```

This is the original code:
(don't wonder about the missing if ... > 0. Obj-C don't enter the for loop, if xmlNodes is nil. Swift brings a runtime error)

```
- (NSArray*)getElementsByTagName:(NSString*)tagName {
    NSString *xPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".//%@", tagName];
    NSArray *xmlNodes = [self.xmlElement nodesForXPath:xPath error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *htmlNodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSXMLElement *el in xmlNodes) {
        HTMLNode *node = [HTMLNode initWithXMLElement:el];
        [htmlNodes addObject:node];
    }
    return htmlNodes;
}
```

Is this a problem with swift or do I oversee some code error?

Comment: Some guy benchmarked Swift vs ObjC and found that under optimizations, Swift is faster. Without optimizations, Swift is much slower than ObjC. Can you try your benchmark with optimizations on and post your results?

Comment: I think Algorithms have dependency over the programming languages. So we cannot measure speed of operation performed for single algorithm. Effectively we can measure it with sorting/searching algorithms.

Comment: Yes that's true and I understand it. I don't say, that Swift is slower (who the hell gave me a downvote??)! I just want to know, if it's a code error or maybe a problem with the casting or whatever. I can't see a way to optimize my code, therefore I asked!

Comment: Some eager fanboy probably downvoted you so I upvoted you for balance. I think that it's a good question and that even if your conclusion is wrong ("swift is slower") we can all learn something from a competent answer.

Comment: I think we should use a simple test case to compare perfomance in general, there's too much going on in this case.
@JackWu can you post a link to the bechmarks you mention?

Comment: You need to say whether you are compiling with optimisation switched on or not.  In my experience, unoptimised Swift can be orders of magnitude slower than optimised Swift.

Answer (score 9):

Remember, these two environments are bridged, which means that if your swift code calls into Objective-C objects, you're still going to pay the dynamic dispatch (i.e. `objc_msgSend`) penalty. In this loop, the things you're looping over are in an `NSArray` so all the looping calls (presumably `NSFastEnumeration`) still have to traverse the bridge every time.

The "real" speedup is going to come from sections of code that are pure swift and don't hit the Objective-C bridge. This is really the same discussion as the old "C++ is faster" argument. C++ is faster, but only if you're not constantly calling back into Objective-C.

In an ideal world, the best strategy here would be to use a native swift XML parser (which probably doesn't exist at this point) and have your model and controller objects all be pure swift with shim classes for where they cross the border into Objective-C. If we were talking about C++ instead of swift, I would say that if you rewrote your model and controller objects as native C++ objects and then used a pure C++ XML parser, and only used Objective-C at the point where you had to interact with the UI, you would expect significant performance gains.

When swift has to interact with Objective-C libraries, it can't make those libraries any faster than they were before, so naturally they can only be "as fast" or "slower." The real wins will come from pure swift code. It's likely that you could also get some gains by using swift to call directly into C (or C++) libraries but the generic (i.e. not-Apple-provided) P/Invoke story (to use a .NET word) is not very clear at the moment.

Comment: THANKS !!! That's exactly _that_ explanation, that makes absolutely sense for me. Maybe I will try to find and use a c xml parser. After that I will report...