# Loading c dylib

Tags: swift

How can I import a c dynamic library (.dylib) into Swift? I want to use libxml2.dylib. I added it as a framework to my project, but I can't use it.

`import libxml` says: `No such module`

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work either. Also I tried xml, xml2

Comment: The [import documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_475) might help. Maybe try `import libxml2.dylib`?

Comment: dylib is not framework, I think you need to load it in an objc method and expose it in *-Bridge-Header.h, then call that method in swift.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use C functionality functions in Swift, they must be exposed via an Objective-C wrapper and a bridging header. See also [the Apple interop documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26).

Comment: Ah thank you. I thought I could avoid the way with the bridge (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030993/swift-seems-to-be-slower-as-objective-c-in-loops/

Answer (score 1):

You need to

```
 #import <libxml/tree.h>
 #import <libxml/parser.h>
```

into [YOUR-APP]-Bridging-Header.h