# Is there a way to work with Foundation objects (NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary) in Swift without bridging?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

When using Swift, the Cocoa frameworks are declared to return native Swift types, even though the frameworks are actually returning Objective-C objects. Likewise, the methods takes Swift types as parameters, where that makes sense.

Suppose I want to call a Cocoa method that (in Objective-C) would give me an NSArray and then pass that to a Cocoa method that takes an `NSArray`. With code like this:

```
let a: [AnyObject] = [] // Imagine calling a method that returns a huge NSArray.
let mutable = NSMutableArray()
mutable.addObjectsFromArray(a)
```

It looks like the huge `NSArray` is going to get bridged to a Swift array when assigned to `a` and then bridged back to an `NSArray` when passed as a parameter. At least that's how it seems from profiling and looking at the disassembly.

Is there a way to avoid these potentially slow conversions when I don't need to actually work with the array in Swift? When I'm just receiving it from Cocoa and then passing it back to Cocoa?

At first, I thought that it would help to add type information for `a`:

```
let a: NSArray = [] // Imagine calling a method that returns a huge NSArray.
let mutable = NSMutableArray()
mutable.addObjectsFromArray(a as [AnyObject])
```

But then I have to convert the parameter to a Swift array later or the compiler will complain.

Furthermore, the disassembly for code like:

```
let c: NSArray = mutable.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 50))
```

shows calls to `__TF10Foundation22_convertNSArrayToArrayurFGSqCSo7NSArray_GSaq__` and `__TFer10FoundationSa19_bridgeToObjectiveCurfGSaq__FT_CSo7NSArray`, seemingly converting the return value to Swift and then back to Objective-C. (This happens even with Release builds.) I had hoped that by typing `c` as `NSArray` there would be no bridging necessary.

I'm concerned that this could lead to [inefficiencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030993/swift-seems-to-be-slower-as-objective-c-in-loops) with very large data structures, with many disparate conversions of regular ones, and with collections that are lazy/proxied because they are not necessarily large but may be expensive to compute. It would be nice to be able to [receive](https://twitter.com/kluivers/status/712330976677007360) such an array from Objective-C code and pass it back without having to realize all of the elements of the array if they are never accessed from Swift.

This is a very [different](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8972810) [performance](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1040248#1040248) model than with Core Foundation/Foundation where the bridging was toll-free. There are so many cases where code passes objects back and forth assuming that it will be O(1), and if these are invisibly changed to O(n) the outer algorithms could become quadratic or worse. It's not clear to me what one is supposed to do in this case. If there is no way to turn off the bridging, it seems like everything that touches those objects would need to be rewritten in Objective-C.

Here is some sample timing code based on the above example:

```
NSArray *getArray() {
    static NSMutableArray *result;
    if (!result) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            [array addObjectsFromArray:@[@1, @2, @3, @"foo", @"bar", @"baz"]];
        }
        result = array;
    }
    return result;
}

@interface ObjCTests : XCTestCase
@end
@implementation ObjCTests
- (void)testObjC { // 0.27 seconds
    [self measureBlock:^{
        NSArray *a = getArray();
        NSMutableArray *m = [NSMutableArray array];
        [m addObjectsFromArray:a];
    }];
}
@end

class SwiftTests: XCTestCase {
    func testSwift() { // 0.33 seconds
        self.measureBlock() {
            let a: NSArray = getArray() as NSArray
            let m = NSMutableArray()
            m.addObjectsFromArray(a as [AnyObject])
        }
    }

    func testSwiftPure() { // 0.83 seconds
        self.measureBlock() {
            let a = getArray()
            var m = [AnyObject]()
            m.appendContentsOf(a)
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, `testSwift()` is about 22% slower than `testObjC()`. Just for fun, I tried doing the array append with the native Swift array, and this was much slower.

A related issue is that when Objective-C code passes Swift code an `NSMutableString`, the Swift `String` ends up with a *copy* of the mutable string. This is good in the sense that it won’t be unexpectedly mutated behind Swift’s back. But if all you need to do is pass a string to Swift and look at it briefly, this copy could add unexpected overhead.

Comment: Have you made timing tests? If not you are just guessing. Don't guess, measure. Also why are you  creating a `NSMutableArray` and assigning it to a `let` variable which is immutable" `let mutable = NSMutableArray()`.

Comment: @zaph Yes, in one timing test that I did, 25% of the time seemed to be spent bridging back and forth. `let` in this case just means that I won't be assigning another object to that variable. The object itself can still be mutable, just like if it were, say, an `NSMutableURLRequest` that has no Swift equivalent.

Comment: Can you add some code to show the back-and-forth conversion? FYI... you can initialize an `NSMutableArray` from an `NSArray`: `let mutable = NSMutableArray(array: a)`

Comment: @ZoffDino Do you mean that you want to see the disassembly? It is odd that `NSMutableArray(array:)` can accept an `NSArray` whereas `a.arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray(a)` does not work.

Comment: @MichaelTsai since Xcode 6.3, implicit conversation between `NSArray` and `Array` has been disabled. You will be better off by sticking to the old Coca classes (`NSArray` / `NSMutableArray`) or the Swift mutability keywords (`let` / `var`). Don't flip flop.

Comment: @ZoffDino I don't think your comment really relates to my question. The change in Xcode 6.3 means that now you have to write `as`. It doesn't mean that no conversion is happening. The point of my question is that I want to be able to stick to the Cocoa classes, but the automatic bridging is forcing unwanted conversions. Choosing `let`/`var` is an orthogonal issue.

Comment: @MichaelTsai Can you please post the details of the test you ran that showed 25% bridging time? I'd like to try reproducing it. Also, do you remember whether your timing tests had compiler optimizations enabled? Finally, have you experimented with optimizations like `private`, `final`, and `@noescape` to see if they affect the bridging behavior?

Comment: @AaronBrager I no longer have that test code, where the 25% was derived from directly counting the time in the bridging functions in an Activity Monitor sample. However, I've added some example code that uses XCTest for measurement. I used a Release build, so optimizations should be on. It doesn't seem like `private`/`final`/`@noescape` apply to my example.

Comment: @MichaelTsai Thanks for updating your question, I'll take a look in a bit

Answer (score 1):

have you tried making an extension?

```
extension NSMutableArray
{
    func addObjectsFromNSArray(array:NSArray)
    {
         for item in array
         {
              self.addObject(item);
         }
    }
}
```

Now that I had time to actually play with this instead of talking in theory,  I am going to revise my answer

Create an extension, but instead, do it in an objective c file

```
@interface NSMutableArray(Extension)
    - (void)addObjectsFromNSArray:(NSObject*) array;
@end

@implementation NSMutableArray(Extension)
    - (void)addObjectsFromNSArray:(NSObject*) array
{
   [self addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)array];
}
@end
```

I found the code to work a lot faster doing it this way.  (Almost 2x from my tests)

testSwift                4.06 seconds

testSwiftPure            7.97 seconds

testSwiftExtension       2.30 seconds

Comment: Yes, I think approach can work, but it loses type checking, could potentially require wrapping lots of APIs, and could require a lot of code restructuring to avoid directly calling into your Swift code.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately I have not seen any other way to disable the autobridging, so I would probably use this way if I needed a speed increase in a certain circumstance.  I will have to check if I still have the playground at home,  I will add a type check of NSArray, and see how much slower it is.